# Visual studio вылет при запуске без отладчика

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Народ, такой очень странный вопрос, может у кого было... Приложение при отладке нормально работает и полностью функционирует, но при запуске без отладчика (например после установки с помощью PowerShell или любой другой способ) оно вылетает. Почему то мне кажется, что дело в разметке. Но в чем причина понятия не имею. Скинуть весь код разметки будет очень громоздко. Если у кого то были подобные ситуации как исправили?

Comment: Может быть из-за совместимости виндоуса, происходит вылет ?

Comment: @Tode да вряд-ли... Там запускается первая страница и при переходе на другой фрейм происходит вылет...

Comment: А вылет это типа прекращена работа софта/студии ?

Comment: @Tode просто выключается прилога. Причем я даже не могу проверить из-за чего. Тк при запуски из студии все работает замечательно...

Comment: Если при запуске из студии все ок, то проверяйте, что все необходимые для работы библиотеки копируются в выходную папку проекта. Отсутствие необходимой DLL рядом с программой вполне может и будет приводить к падению приложения, при любом обращении к классу из отсутствующей библиотеки.

Comment: А ещё сильно поможет исключение, с которым происходит вылет.

Comment: Посмотрите в журнале событий Windows. Там должна быть информация об исключении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйся методом [Debugger.Launch()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch(v=vs.110).aspx). Дойдя до этого вызова, программа приостановит выполнение и выдаст приглашение на подключение отладчика. Установи в параметрах исключений галку на остановку при возникновении любого CLR исключения. Если приложение вообще запускается, это поможет определить причину ошибки.

Если приложение не запускается от слова совсем, в журнале событий должна быть запись о том, что что-то пошло не так.

Наиболее вероятная причина состоит в том, что ты выполняешь какие-либо действия (н.п. с файловой системой), требующие дополнительных прав пользователя или привилегий администратора, а выполнение из-под студии и выполнение через PS происходит под разными пользователями или с разными правами.

Опять же, если ты работаешь с файловой системой и используешь относительные пути, проблема может заключаться в смене рабочего каталога. Но опять же, информация об этом должна попасть в виде исключения, либо в твои обработчики, если они есть (если нет - плохо), либо в журнал событий.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, буду пробовать)